# Symfony test serialize

Tags: php, testing, symfony, serialization

This is my test file

```
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', $this->getUrlOfRoute($this->routeStep1));
    $buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('next_step');

    $form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form(array(
        'form[name]' => '__davidc',
            ), 'POST');

    $crawler = $this->client->submit($form);

    $container = $this->client->getContainer();


    $session = $container->get('session')->get('maSession');
```

This is my controller :

```
if (!$form->getData()['name']) {

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('error_page'));
    }
    $data = $form->getData();
    $name = $data['name'];
    $unObject = new ObjectPerso();
    $unObject->setName($name);

    $test= serialize($unObject);

    $this->get('session')->set('maSession',  serialize($unObject));
    var_dump($this->get('session')->get('maSession'));
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('step2'));
```

My problem is that when I execute the test, it does not pass the serialize. This will return no error or exception but valid test.

Now I want to check the form and the session and I can not because it does not serialize and therefore nothing is not my session variable.

Comment: PHP-CLI has no sessions and it's a very bad practice to store objects in session!

Comment: What is the solution for keeping an object from one stage to another ?

Comment: Better store the raw form data and construct the object in the last step and save it.

Comment: Do you have an example ? Because I don't know how to do that.I think the data will be lost